# How to ensure admission control plugins are removed and will not be enforced in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I was removed the LimitRanger admission plugin by edited the line --enable-admission-plugins= in kube-apiserver.yaml in /etc/kubernetes/manifests.
Once saved the file,immediately the existing kupe-api pod kube-apiserver-master.k8s deleted and recreated automatically.
Able to see the LimitRanger plugin is not listing in restarted kube-api server process

```
 kube-apiserver --advertise-address=192.168.56.4 --allow-privileged=true --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --insecure-port=0 --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=6443 --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
```

But now i have submitted a deployment without mentioning cpu,memory resource requests and limits as like below

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
 name: kubia-dep
spec:
 replicas: 3
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: dev
 template:
  metadata:
    name: dep-spec
    labels:
     app: dev
  spec:
   containers:
   - name: kubia-dep-cn
     image: luksa/kubia:v2
```

```
[root@master manifests]# kubectl get po
NAME                         READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
curl-custom-sa               2/2     Running                      0          4d2h
kubia-dep-74cb8b894c-47m96   1/1     Running                      0          14m
kubia-dep-74cb8b894c-gnzt8   1/1     Running                      0          14m
kubia-dep-74cb8b894c-h26nv   1/1     Running                      0          14m
```

But i'm seeing limitRanger plugin was applied by checking in kubectl describe po kubia-dep-74cb8b894c-47m96

```
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/limit-ranger:
                LimitRanger plugin set: cpu, memory request for container kubia-dep-cn; cpu, memory limit for container kubia-dep-cn
Containers:
  kubia-dep-cn:
    Container ID:   docker://d151dc4b589f70359587ebd594d1e40cc8797ae0be25527cc2b0e92bd2c20303
    Image:          luksa/kubia:v3
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://docker.io/luksa/kubia@sha256:bcae4c20b355376d86bb34db0c9637a2e72058db5a66af82c868a2cfdcb0ac80
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 26 Nov 2019 23:33:57 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     200m
      memory:  100Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     10Mi
```

So how LimitRanger plugin is enforced even after removed?Is there any additional steps we have to do for deforce this LimitRanger plugin? or removing directly from apiserver manifest file is not the proper way?

Comment: In recent versions v1.10+  LimitRanger plugin is enabled by default. Adding/removing it to/from `--enable-admission-plugins` list doesn't have any effect.  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/58684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if a limitrange is active :

`kubectl get limitranges`

alse check if you have resourcequotas defined :

`kubetcl get resourcequotas`

Comment: resourcequotas i found and alreay deleted.Nowi found limitranges from kubectl get limitranges and removed and it is working fine now.I thought of we remove admission plugin from apiserver,it will not be enforced.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I was removed the LimitRanger admission plugin by edited the line --enable-admission-plugins= in kube-apiserver.yaml in /etc/kubernetes/manifests.

Have you tried --disable-admission-plugins ?

[K8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#how-do-i-turn-off-an-admission-controller) says that:

> The Kubernetes API server flag  `disable-admission-plugins`  takes a comma-delimited list of admission control plugins to be disabled, **even if they are in the list of plugins enabled by default**.

```
kube-apiserver --disable-admission-plugins=PodNodeSelector,AlwaysDeny
```

To see which admission plugins are enabled:

```
kube-apiserver -h | grep enable-admission-plugins
```

In 1.16, plugins **enabled by default** are:

```
NamespaceLifecycle, LimitRanger, ServiceAccount, TaintNodesByCondition, Priority, DefaultTolerationSeconds, DefaultStorageClass, StorageObjectInUseProtection, PersistentVolumeClaimResize, MutatingAdmissionWebhook, ValidatingAdmissionWebhook, RuntimeClass, ResourceQuota
```

Comment: Hi Nick,If you installed k8s using kubeadm then  kube-apiserver command won't wotk.I mean no kube-apiserver command option

Comment: Aha, got it. So, am I right that you have achieved the desired result already?

Comment: @user10912187, You can run kube-apiserver commands in kube-apiserver container, but @Nick told that if you want to disable **default plugin** (e.g. LimitRanger), you have to add `--disable-admission-plugins=LimitRanger` to `kube-apiserver` arguments in the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` After that all limitranges objects will be kept in place, but they wont apply to any new Pods,or PVCs even if they fall out of existing limitrange constraints.